Does copper(II) hydroxide dissolve in ammonia solution?
According to University of Oregon — Chemistry Interactive Demonstrations and Educational Resources — Copper-Ammonia Complex, the equilibrium constant for the formation of copper(II) hydroxide is relatively larger compared to the formation of tetraamminecopper(II).
This means that $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ dissolve in ammonia solution poorly. Yet in fact, it does react really well. Where does this contradiction come from?

Have you done the calculation involving the provided constants? // Comparison of constants must consider also different stoichiometries and present concentrations.// CH SE questions are supposed to be self-contained, involving all essential info, with the links serving just as additional  reference original text or for further reading. Questing alone should be fully valid even if links stopped working.

See also Schweitzer reagent and production of "copper silk". In the process, cellulose is  dissolved in the ammonia solution of copper(II) hydroxide(dark violet).

The equilibrium constant for the formation of copper(II) hydroxide can hardly be compared to the formation of tetraamminecopper(II), because these two constants don't have the same unit.

What do you mean by different unit?

The equilibrium constant for the formation of copper(II) hydroxide is $\ce{[Cu^{2+}][OH-]^2}$, so it is expressed in $mol^3 L^{-3}$.  The equilibrium constant for  the formation of tetraamminecopper(II) is $\ce{\frac{[Cu(NH3)4^{2+}]}{[Cu^{2+}][NH3]^4}}$. It is expressed in $mol^{-4}L^{4}$

I don't quite get the idea. You mean that we should not calculate the equilibrium constant for the dissolution of copper(II) hydroxide by ammonia?

1/ You have the given [NH3]. 2/ Calculate the equilibrium [OH-]. 3/ Calculate the equilibrium [Cu^2+]. 4/ Calculate the equilibrium [Cu(NH3)4^2+].

Not quite: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70910/do-copper-and-ammonium-hydroxide-react
